# Apps whitelisted in AFWall+ without my knowledge

Tags: security, malware, firewall

I've installed a firewall (AFWall+) on my phone, and I've manually whitelisted every app I wanted to allow accessing the Internet, including system apps. So everything is blocked by default, and I add apps to the whitelist as necessary until what I need works and nothing beyond that.

I've just discovered some apps in the whitelist that I never whitelisted myself and don't even remember ever seeing before to be honest. These are:

- "Intent Filter Verification Service"
- "Market Feedback Agent"
- "Print Service Recommendation Service"
- "Google Partner Set Up"

From what I can see, these are from Google, although I'm not clear on what they do (except the Feedback Agent).

How could this happen?

---

**System details**:

- Device: Samsung Galaxy S5 Duos (SM-G900FD)
- OS: LineageOS 14.1
- Android version: 7.1.2
- The phone is rooted with SuperSU.

Answer (score 2):

Guess you didn't read this [explanation by developer regarding system apps](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/System-Applications-to-block-or-allow). You need to consciously blacklist them if you want, by default they are white listed.

- Google Partner Setup

> No one seems to know what this does and what data it transmits/receives
>   Rec: Block

- Market Feedback agent

> If blocked, cannot use Google to submit feedback to app developers when apps crashes.
>   Rec: Block if not using the Google Play store, otherwise allow for all connection types except LAN

Other two are not covered in this list so you could ask developer on his [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1957231). If you aren't using Print services, it should be safe to disable IMO

Comment: You've guessed correctly, I hadn't read that. However, AFWall+ doesn't have a concept of blacklisting separately from a whitelist. As I've mentioned in the post, I disabled everything, and I've been enabling  ("whitelisting") manually whatever was necessary. I never enabled those apps, yet I found them enabled. The question is: how could this happen?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used this app so it's possible I am mixing up white/black list. Yet, these being **system** apps are by default enabled as explained  by developer. You need to disable them based on your need and suitability.